# Get all selected Accessibility Options in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, accessibility

I would like to check the user's accessibility settings like font size, inverted colors, and all the ones that are relevant.

I want to do this to evaluate and asses how to better my user experience based on the accessibility settings that users are using.

I could find the `getResources()` api for Android but nothing for iOS through a quick search online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to check for some of them individually.

A few examples:

Is Voice over running

```
UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
```

Has the user inverted colours:

```
UIAccessibilityIsInvertColorsEnabled()
```

A few auto complete options for `UIAccessibilityIs`....

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to check the user's accessibility settings...

Every accessibility options defined in the settings are not necessary reachable.

I suggest to take a look at:

- [This list](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-options) containing all the accessibility options with their notification name *(ObjC + Swift)* to be informed when their state changes hereunder:
  [image]
- This [detailed way](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/criteria-ios.html#accessibility-options) of activating each one of them on your device settings.

This list of accessibility options is exhaustive until new features are exposed by Apple itself.