# Measuring Number of Users with Accessibility Requirements on Mobile

Tags: android, ios, accessibility

I work on an app with iOS and Android versions and am looking to know more about our users who have accessibility requirements.

There are two pieces of info I'd love to have:

1. How many of our users on iOS and Android already use accessibility features like voice over, switch control, font scaling, or color and motion settings (amongst many other options).
2. How many users generally use these features?

I'm having a very hard time using the Google to answer these questions, so any advice would be well received.

Comment: i think the answer to this question will be very different for android and ios, it might be worth asking different questions for each specific platform, unless you're using a cross platform framework, in which case you should add that info to your question

Comment: We're not using a cross-platform framework and, yeah, the answers are likely different on the two platforms. If someone has info about either iOS or Android I'd love to hear it.

Comment: not saying this is a bad question, was merely a suggestion as i would actually like to see answers to this, was just trying to make it more focused

Comment: For , you have a11y events to listen if you want to know when these options are used ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-options. 
Take a look at this answer if you want to read the detailed list of these possible options ⟹ https://stackoverflow.com/a/59106538/3825084.
About android, this kind of information may be available... somewhere. 